# NodeJs read JSON file

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I am tying to read a json file using NodeJs

my code is pretty basic,

```
  var obj = require("./sample.json");
  console.log(obj[0]);
```

The sample.json file contains a stringified JSON like this,

```
"[{\"sample\":\"good\",\"val\":76159}]"
```

However the console.log output is '[' not the first element in the variable. I have tried opening the file in the long way like this as well.

```
var obj;
fs.readFile('sample.json', 'utf8', function (err, data) {
  if (err) throw err;
  obj = JSON.parse(data);
  console.log(obj[0]);
});
```

But here also the output is '[' why is the json file not properly parsed? How can I fix it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try printing the `data`?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/xgfgmx08/ if data is what you said, it should work. double check what's inside data

Comment: @BeNdErR can you try code where it opens a json in a local computer, I guess the problem is the way we open the file because the example works fine, is there an issue in the way we open the json file?

Comment: @rksh try to console.log(data) as soon as you read it. What's the output?

Comment: Have you made: `var fs = require('fs');` and tested that you get `data` once you read the file as commented by @BeNdErR ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your file should contain:

```
[{"sample":"good","val":76159}]
```

If it contains

```
"[{\"sample\":\"good\",\"val\":76159}]"
```

Then it is encoded twice. It is still valid JSON because it is a string, but this JSON does not represent the JavaScript Object:

```
[{
  sample:"good",
  val:76159
}]
```

But a string with the content `[{"sample":"good","val":76159}]`.

If you add a second parse (the first one is implicitly done by the `require`):

```
var obj = JSON.parse(require("./sample.json"));
console.log(obj[0]);
```

then you will see that the the correct information is logged.
So your initial problem is that you stored the value the wrong way in `./sample.json`.

Answer (score 4):

[info.json]

```
[{
    "name" : "Young",
    "age" : 100,
    "skill" : "js"
}]
```

[main.js]

```
var jsonObj = require('./info.json');
console.log(jsonObj[0]);
```

[result]

```
{ name: 'Young', age: 100, skill: 'js' }
```